# Where do I specify MaxConcurrent calls in Azure Service bus

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

Below is my Azure Function App code which triggers on a Service bus topic. After certain delay, I run across this error in my console "*The lock supplied is invalid. Either the lock expired, or the message has already been removed from the queue. while removing message*".

On googling and referring other stack overflow posts, one solution that has been asked to try is specifying the Maxconcurrent calls but I couldn't figure out where do I specify that and how do I do it in my below code. If someone can help me on that and also if any other alternative I should try for this error.

```
 public class TabularData
{
    

    [FunctionName( "ProcessTableData" )]
    public async Task Run( [ServiceBusTrigger("twister-events", "tabulardata-processor",
        Connection = "AzureServiceBusString")]
        string SbMsg, ExecutionContext context,
        ILogger log )
    {
        try
        {
            MyProject.CreateDefaultLoggerFactory();
            TableStorageManager manager = new TableStorageManager();
            if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( SbMsg ) )
            {
                log.LogInformation( $"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {SbMsg}" );
                TableStorageConfiguration rulesList = GetConfiguration( context.FunctionAppDirectory, "DataFileConfiguration.json" );
                await ProcessServiceBusMessage( SbMsg, rulesList, manager );
            }
        }
        catch( Exception Ex )
        {
            log.LogError( $"Error while uploading tabular data; {Ex.Message}" );
            throw;
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: This is how my host.json file looks like but I still running into same error.

```
{
  "functionTimeout": "05:05:00",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "prefetchCount": 100,
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": false,        
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 32,
        "maxAutoRenewDuration": "05:00:00"
      },
      "sessionHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": false,
        "messageWaitTimeout": "05:00:30",
        "maxAutoRenewDuration": "05:55:00",
        "maxConcurrentSessions": 16
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error basically means that the Function App couldn't process the message during the lock duration time which is 30 seconds by default, an alternative solution would be to increase to lock duration from 30 to 60 and see if that helps on decreasing the amount of lock invalid exceptions.
Regarding where to specify the "maxConcurrentCalls" that is done in the host.json settings file

```
 },
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "maxConcurrentCalls": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what will be maximum value of Concurrent calls which I can give?? and the alternative solution to increase lock duration. Where do i do that??

Comment: Can you check my question. I have updated with my host.json file but I still receive the same error

Comment: You can increase the lock duration by recreating the queue/topic in the service bus, you will see the option during the creation process.
Also, are you receiving this error constantly or sporadically ? I wonder if it could be that you have autocomplete set to false in host.json and not calling complete for the message that was process somewhere in your code
In case you get the error for all the messages, then try setting autocomplete to "true" and let me know how it goes.

Comment: should i remove the sessionHandlerOptions from my host.json file.the autocomplete to true is meant for messageHandlerOptions? Also what is the max duration I can keep for lock duration considering I have around 500 messages `coming one by one and the function take this message one by one and then do some filtering and querying and pass it to Azur tabular storage. it takes around 20/30 sec for each message

Comment: You can try updating it to 60s which will be around 6 minutes in total taking into consideration that you have a maxautorenewduration of 5 minutes. 
If only some messages are not getting processed then you should not worry about the autocomplete, l guess you are manually calling complete()
Also you might want to look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63576127/messagelocklostexception-the-lock-supplied-is-invalid-either-the-lock-expossibility
As the prefetchCount set to 100 might be an issue here